# How to hold more than one values in XML element?

Tags: c#

xWaarde.Value is overriding with new values and flushing old values.

how to stored multiple values in Xelement.

```
private XElement[] AddCoordinatenList(XElement childElements)
{
        XmlNode xmlCoordinatenNode = Utility.GetMappingValues(Constants.BMCoordinaten, ConnectionType.BM);
        XmlNode xWaardeNode = Utility.GetMappingValues(Constants.BMXwaarde, ConnectionType.BM);
        XmlNode yWaardeNode = Utility.GetMappingValues(Constants.BMYwaarde, ConnectionType.BM);
        XmlNode CoordinateX = Utility.GetMappingValues(Constants.XCoordinate, ConnectionType.BM);
        XmlNode CoordinateY = Utility.GetMappingValues(Constants.YCoordinate, ConnectionType.BM);
        var coordinatenList = from document in childElements.DescendantsAndSelf() where document.Name.LocalName == xmlCoordinatenNode.Name select document;
        List<XElement> xcoordinatenList = new List<XElement>();

        XElement xWaarde = new XElement(CoordinateX.Name);
        XElement yWaarde = new XElement(CoordinateY.Name);

        if (coordinatenList.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (XElement element in coordinatenList.Descendants())

            {
                if (element.Name.LocalName == xWaardeNode.Name)
                {
                    xWaarde.Value = element.Value;


                }
                if (element.Name.LocalName == yWaardeNode.Name)
                {
                    yWaarde.Value = element.Value;

                }
            }
        }

        return xcoordinatenList.ToArray();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like your question is a bit lacking here. When entering code, please make sure each line has at least 4 spaces before it. That way, the code will register as such. In addition the question you are asking is not very clear.

Comment: my loop is running 4 time eith 4 different vaues ---->xWaarde.Value and yWaarde.Value overring the values. that is last 3rd and 4th values are stored in xWaarde.Value and yWaarde.Value ...and 1st and 2nd values are flusing and i want to stord all 4 values in coordinatenList.Descendants()

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Use Attributes:

```
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("name1", <value>);
element.Add(attribute);

attribute = new XAttribute("name2", <value>);
element.Add(attribute);
```

You can also add a list of child elements or add all strings as one string, separated by a comma for instance.